# Backing up a solution/project to create a skeleton in c#

Tags: c#

Maybe this is the wrong question. I don't understand the hierarchy/relationship between solutions and projects, so I'll describe my goal first. I have a forms application which works. I want to copy everything in it to another folder on the same PC with a different name which reflects the purpose of a new forms app I want to build. I want to use the old parent which I copied as a skeleton, a starting point. I've tried copying the whole WindowsFormsApplication1 and renaming it, but when it builds, it refers to stuff in the old parent folder. I want each of these to be totally self contained, not reference something above the new folder I just made with the skeleton.

Can someone describe the relationship between projects, solutions, the folder which gets created called WindowsFormsApplicationx and the .sln file? If this is too general, I'd be happy with just some step-by-steps to accomplish my goal.

Thanks for your patience,
Lamar

---

Thanks onlinecop, this helps but I’m still not all the way there.

When I created the forms application, it made a set of files and directories in the Studio2010/Projects directory:

WindowsFormsApplication2.sln

WindowsFormsApplication2.suo

WindowsFormsApplication2 (folder)

```
Bin (folder)

Obj (folder)

Properties (folder)
```

Form1.cs

Form1.Designer.cs

Form1.resx

Program.cs

WindowsFormsApplication2.csproj

WindowsFormsApplication2.csproj.user

I used Forms Designer to make a presentation layer, which although it doesn’t change much, it does change some.

I want to start with all of these and may or may not make changes to them but I will want to change all of their names.

Besides changing the names, most of my changes are in the Form1.cs and wherever Forms Designer keeps its changes. Since it is a graphical input and not text, I don’t know where it stores its stuff.

I’d like to do this without disturbing anything with the originals.

Almost none are unit tests, and most are new, addressing different applications so I don’t want to depend on a version control tool.

I’d like to *not* use them by reference, but instead by copy because I want the parents sequestered and unchanged.

So it would seem that I would want these to have completely different solutions, not projects inside of a solution….is this right?

Will the “Add Existing” do this for me, and where should I do it

As I’m reading the tutorials, my impression is that basically a solution is associated with an application and projects are sub-entities which might be incremental changes to host unit tests or debugging.

So since I want to make a completely different application, which I do not want to have confused with the parent, I’m thinking I want a new solution. But I want to use most of what I had in the parent so how can I create a new solution and populate it with the contents of the old source files and rename them? I’d like to not have them called Forms1.cs and WindowsFormsApplication2…..more something descriptive of what they are, like NeutronMigrationAnalysis…

If I’m asking the wrong question, it might become clearer if I understood when I should create a new solution instead of a single one with a gazillion projects in it.

Thanks!

Lamar

Comment: have you considered using a version control system? branching solves this problem

Answer (score 0):

A *solution* contains multiple *projects*.

Let's say that you create a Unit Test. That test will run methods that you've created in a different *project*, just to ensure that those methods work correctly. So within this *solution*, you actually have two *projects*: one which is your normal forms app, and one that is a Unit Test which you, as a developer, can see but that end users won't.

The folders are merely hierarchal in nature: It helps you keep your projects separate, and files in places easy for you to find.

So take your original forms project, within your master solution.  Your solution file (usually a .sln file) defines that you have a single project within it, and the directory where it's stored. It usually keeps track of other general or global information as well.

The forms project contains its own project file (usually a .csproj file), and is usually found within whatever subdirectory it was initially started in. That will define all the files that you want included, all of the special build options, the logical layout of your folders, files, and resources, and so on.

When you want to recreate a skeleton project, you will usually create a new, empty *project*. Then, copy all of the source files into it from your form project and "Add existing..." the files so they are seen by *this* project. Doing it this way will prevent the `.csproj` file from being copied from the original project and keeping all those old parent folder files/references.